# Error when commiting to Github from command line

Tags: github

Every time I try and commit changes to GitHub from the command line (after following the tutorial below from GitHub) I get the erorr "fatal: I don't handle protocol 'https:https'"

I'm following this short tutorial from GitHub.

```
Create a new repository on the command line
touch README.md
git init
git add README.md
git commit -m "first commit"
git remote add origin https://github.com/tuzion/baby-companion.git
git push -u origin master
```

Thanks!

-- I'm on a Mac, btw.

Comment: Use the URL that starts with git: instead.

Comment: What version of git do you have? It probably doesn't support the https protocol...

Comment: @lego When I do that it says "fatal: remote origin already exists."

I should specify that I'm getting the error after the 'git push -u origin master' step

Comment: @EugenConstantinDinca 1.8.3.2

Answer (score 0):

Did you input the SSH keys into the Github Account Setting?

Check your account setting/SSH keys..

Comment: The first line of that says "If you have decided not to use the recommended HTTPS method[...]". I assumed I was? Is there a way to enable it before I try generating a key? I'd rather just use HTTPS.